# Jersey REST Character encoding

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

I have some problems concerning charater encoding with gson. 
I have a webservice which sends following JSON response:

```
{
    "version": "v2",
    "result": {
        "class": "SearchSizeBean",
        "result_list": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Bitte w\u00c3\u00a4hlen"
            },
            {
                "id": "21",
                "name": "176"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I request the webservice with following code:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.path(version)
            .path(path)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .method(method.name(), ClientResponse.class, paramMap);

if (response.getStatus() == 200)
{
    responseBody = response.getEntity(String.class);
    ...
}
```

When checking responseBody the resulting string shows exactly the same result as the JSON mentioned above. But after using GSon to convert the JSON string into an Object, the characters are converted wrong:

Parsing with GSON:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .registerTypeAdapter(Transferable.class, new TransferableDeserializer())
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .create();

RestResponse responseDTO = gson.fromJson(responseBody, RestResponse.class);
```

Resulting content:

```
Response: SearchSizeBean[
              resultList={
                  PosSize [id=0, name=Bitte wÃ¤hlen],
                  PosSize [id=21, name=176]
              }
          ]
```

**UPDATE:**

I had copied the wrong JSON content. I have edited the JSON to show the correct JSON string. The data is sent in unicode  `w\u00c3\u00a4`. When I check the response after conversion by GSon it becomes hexadecimal: C3 82 C2 A4

Comment: `"name": "Bitte wÃ¤hlen"` - that should be wählen, right? The data looks like UTF-8 decoded as windows-1252. I'd start by verifying the data from the service. When you look at the raw response bytes in a hex editor ä should be encoded as `C3 A4` in UTF-8.

Comment: How are you getting the string you display at the top of this question?  You mentioned that responseBody had the same thing.  Does this mean you did System.out.println(responseBody) and saw "\u00c3\u00a4" in what was printed?

Comment: `"Bitte w\u00c3\u00a4hlen"` is a Unicode-escaped representation of Bitte wÃ¤hlen. Bitte wählen would be `"Bitte w\u00e4hlen"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the server side php code. I have a script, which was already encoded in UTF-8. I have encoded the string "Bitte wählen" with the php function `utf8_encode()` which led to my problem.

Thank you McDowell, your hints brought me on the right track!

The solution was **not** to use the function and just send the string "Bitte wählen".